# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when try to normilize array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have following numpy.ndarray of numpy.ndarrays with shape of (48870,). Every array of this array of arrays if different length

```
len(scores[0]) is 3
len(scores[1]) is 23
....
```

Here example of what inside of this array

```
scores[:2]

array([array([1202.4756 ,  760.3878 ,  294.78476], dtype=float32),
       array([165.3165 , 210.4493 , 264.7258 , 372.05142, 372.05142, 296.6847 ,
       296.49982, 204.45032, 273.4725 , 187.63795, 165.56761, 113.85246,
       663.18164, 295.74124, 159.70975, 211.40504, 332.69815, 386.15533,
       335.54102, 333.21732, 342.35284, 180.64023, 944.4986 ],
      dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

when i call

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
normalize(scores, norm='l2')
```

i got

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`
How to correctly normalize array of arrays ?

I expect normilized array of arrays  something like

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
data = np.array([
    [1000, 10, 0.5],
    [765, 5, 0.35],
    [800, 7, 0.09], ])
data = normalize(data, axis=0, norm='max')
print(data)
>>[[ 1.     1.     1.   ]
[ 0.765  0.5    0.7  ]
[ 0.8    0.7    0.18 ]]

enter code here
```

Comment: It's a ragged array; `scores[:2]` is shape (2,). What do you expect to happen when you call `normalize`?

Comment: What `normalize` are you using?  Are you trying to 'normalize' the array as a whole thing, or normalize the subarrays individually?  Either way, you have to work with one numeric array at a time.  Think of this array as a list of arrays.

Comment: I am sorry, i updated my question

Comment: @enke i showed example of data inside array

Comment: What you expect to be computed is still missing (eg. the output).

Comment: @JérômeRichard could you please clarify ?

Comment: You said that `normalize(scores, norm='l2')` throw an error and you want "*to correctly normalize array of arrays*" but this is unclear so this is why previous comments explicitly requested "*What do you expect to happen when you call normalize?*" and the edit does not make this more clear.

Comment: `data` is a 2d numeric array.  `scores` is not.  You could do `np.normalize(scores[0])`, and so on, but you can't apply it to the whole of `scores`.  Do you understand the difference between the `data` array and the `scores` one?